# C++ : Member reference base type 'char *' is not a structure or union

Tags: c, substring, c-strings, function-definition

```
void find_substring(char * str_for_search_in, char * substring)
{
    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str_for_search_in) - strlen(substring); i++)
    {
        if (str_for_search_in.substr(i, strlen(substring)) == substring)
        {
            cout << i << " ";
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag == false)
        cout << "NONE";
}
```

I am converting my program from C++ strings to C strings and stuck on this issue in line 6

What's the issue here?

It was length.substring everywhere previously, i changed them to strlen() so they fit char *

I've tried changing data types somewhere but that didn't work

Comment: `str_for_search_in` is **not** a `std::string` but an old c style string. It does not have a method `substr` (or any other method).

Comment: C `const char*` pointer doesn't have any member functions, as c generally doesn't support that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters the function in C should be declared like

```
int find_substring( const char * str_for_search_in, const char * substring);
```

It does not change the passed strings so its parameters should be declared with the qualifier `const`. And the function should not output any message. It is the caller of the function will decide whether to output a message. The function just should return a  value (0 or 1) that the caller of the function can check.

This for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str_for_search_in) - strlen(substring); i++)
```

at least has a wrong condition, You should write it like for example

```
for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(str_for_search_in) - strlen(substring); i++)
```

But this work only in case when `strlen(str_for_search_in)` is indeed greater than or equal to `strlen(substring)`.

Also there are redundant calls of `strlen`.

Character arrays do not have member functions. So this expression

```
str_for_search_in.substr(i, strlen(substring))
```

is invalid.

And to compare strings in your for loop you need to use standard C string function `strncmp` declared in the header `<string.h>`.

Pay attention to that within your function you could use standard C string function `strstr`  for example the following way

```
int find_substring( const char * str_for_search_in, const char * substring)
{
    return strstr( str_for_search_in, substring ) != NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were using `std::string` which has `substr` method, but now switched to raw-strings (`char*`), that are plain data types. You can make use of pointer-arithmetic for a comparison.

In the same way, there is no `operator==` for raw-strings (in this case you will be comparing pointers), in general prefer `strcmp`, though in this case it may not be possible because your substrings may not end in a null character.

As a side note, take into consideration that `strlen` has O(n) complexity, so calling it every time in your for loop is inefficient, pre-compute it.

I recommend you to take a look at string operations in C, rather than C++.